# How do i call a layout from a module controller in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

This is the PermissionModule file:

```
<?php
class PermissionsModule extends CWebModule{
    public $defaultController = "site";

}
?>
```

this is the controller content from the module/permission:

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->layout = '//layouts/softvision-layout';
        $this->render('main'); 
    }

}
```

this is the content from protected/views/layout/custom-layout.php:

```
<?php 
echo 1;
?>
```

My problem is that it doesn't display the echo 1. Why ?

Comment: is that your complete code? In your actionIndex you are missing the rendering of the view that is supposed to use the layout.

Comment: yep. this is my full code

Comment: Than that is your problem: you should add something like $this->render('view_name'); after the setting of the property layout because it will trigger the display of the layout itself.

Comment: I created a view in my module called main.php, but now i getting this : SiteController cannot find the requested view "main".

Comment: I noticed another problem: you are setting //layouts while the path should be //layout (if that is the actual structure in your app)). To answer your last question, you should place the view in the right place. First of all, try to place the view "main" in the general app (not in the module), to see if the code is working so far. One problem at a time.

Comment: Now it loads the view the problem was a slash before my view. but the main problem still persits. it does not know about the layout. I put an echo 1; exit(); But it loads always the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout structure is incorrect. Layouts should have `<?php echo $content; ?>` code. This will output the view inside of layout file. For example suppose this is your layout file:

```
<div class="container">
   <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
```

And suppose this is view file:

```
  <h1><?php echo "hello"; ?></h1>
```

Now, when you render the view, the result will be like this:

```
<div class="container">
   </h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the content from my laypout  <?php  echo 2; exit();echo $content; ?> . The fact is that it does not know about the layout. Maybe it is not declared well on the controller. I don't know. Can you take a look? thx and it loads the view

Comment: Why the `exit()`? Just echo whatever you want and then `$content` and you should be good

Comment: Try to remove `exit();` from your layout file.